# staining / dimming newly installed bright white concrete sidewalk slab with iron sulfate

Tags: concrete

I'd like to darken a newly installed (and bright white) concrete slab so it doesn't stand out so starkly next to the older slabs.  I've read that a mixture of coffee grounds and iron sulfate can be used to this end. Those ingredients are combined with water, strained, and spread on like a wash and allowed to sit.  But the only iron sulfate I can find is a mineral supplement for shrubs and lawn-care. Will it do?

Comment: It is new, I would just leave it to time to age it naturally, maybe a year or two.  Trying to speed it up, will seldom match it to the older ones anyway, too light or too dark.

Comment: I'm not trying to match, just dim the contrast a bit. Make the new one look like wet sand instead of toothpaste white.

Comment: The originals are probably 70 years old.

Comment: You presumably already have the coffee grounds, so you could start with those alone and see if it helps...

Comment: @Ecnerwal  Actually I don't. I'm going to have to go on a caffeine jag to dim that slab. That will probably affect my sense of the color contrast. Heisenberg-Caffeine principle.

Comment: You can ask a jittery neighbor - most folks are not shy about sharing the used grounds.

Comment: If you can get some wet dead leaves, those often upset folks that like shiny white concrete by staining it. Easy to try if you have a patch of forest, might be hard in tidy suburbia unless you are making leaf mold with them yourself, or know someone who is. Might be a bit lurking under the hedges.

Comment: Would try just plain dirt and maybe some water.  Can either make a very wet flowing mud solution and pour over the slab and let dry,   Second idea is to make dryer mud and spread over the slab and ground it into the cement with your boots.  If done too dark can wash it away, a stain type might not wash away so easy.

Comment: I might put an ad in the local social media for some flamenco dancers and try that mud suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Iron Sulphate (also called Ferrous Sulphate) is indeed a fertilizer. I get it from my local plant growers supply. I have used it to great success for doing decorative staining of concrete. I really like it- it is easy to use (compared to an acid stain) and it is what I would call an "organic" look. It goes towards the dirt color (here the dirt is reddish/ brown). I have never added or tried  coffee grounds.

The trick will be to get the proportions proper for the look you want. It basically "rusts" on the surface of the concrete- so a light dose would make it a "light rusty/yellow/brown" color. A heavy dose can go all the way to really dark (almost black) with reddish/ orange" splotches.

It comes in a crystalline form so it easily dissolves in water. I would recommend starting with 1/2- 1 cup per gallon of water and applying with a pump up hudson type sprayer. Spray the entire concrete surface lightly- enough to wet it but not form puddles. This is best done when not in direct sun (as it will not evaporate quite so quickly). Wait a few hours and check if you want to add more. It is preferable to build up with successive light coats rather than applying too much from the start. You can always add more but almost impossible to go back if it is too dark.

I have to warn you that all concrete will stain differently. And this process will take it towards a dirt color rather than a gray color. the attached photo is all I could find and shows medium to dark coloring. (This photo was actually taken because I liked the water beaded on the surface). This was done by wetting the concrete and then throwing the iron sulphate directly onto the surface and then spraying water onto the surface to melt the crystals. I would think you would want a much lighter color to make your concrete look "aged" rather than "stained".

[image]

Comment: The beading of the water is cool. Thanks for the advice!